# Использование переменных одного класса в другом с++

Tags: c++, классы

Как в одном классе ( BinaryTransformation) использовать переменные(х,у) другого класса (Calculate)?Как потом реализовать это в main? Желательно без дружественных функций. ( Класс BinaryTransformation еще сырой, я знаю, что там пока что ничего не работает)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Calculate
{
private:
    int  x, y;
public:
    Calculate()
    {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
    }
    Calculate(int a, int b)
    {
        x = a;
        y = b;
    }
    void setNum()
    {
        cout << " Enter x:";
        cin >> x;
        cout << "Enter y: ";
        cin >> y;
    }
    void showNum()
    {
        cout << "x= " << x << endl;
        cout << "y= " << y << endl;
    }
    void sum()
    {
        int sum = x + y;
        cout << "Sum = " << sum << endl;
    }
    void sub()
    {
        int sub = x - y;
        cout << "Sub = " << sub << endl;
    }
    void mul()
    {
        int mul = x * y;
        cout << "Mul = " << mul << endl;
    }
    void div()
    {
        if (y == 0)
        {
            cout << "Division by zero" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            int div = x / y;
            cout << "Div = " << div << endl;
        }
    }
};

class BinaryTransformation
{
    const int bitsize;
    int bits[];
public:


        int bits[8];
        for (int i = 0; i < bitsize; ++i)
        {
            if (х % 2 == 0)
            {
                bits[i] = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                bits[i] = 1;
            }
            a = х % 2;
        }
        for (int i = bitsize - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            cout << bits[i] << bits[i] << endl;;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    Calculate n1;
    n1.setNum();
    n1.showNum();
    n1.sum();
    n1.sub();
    n1.mul();
    n1.div();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Сделать их public в классе calculate, или реализовать доступ через методы calculate, если я правильно понял вопрос

Comment: Вам не должно хотеться использовать поля одного класса в другом. Сокрытие полей и есть смысл инкапсуляции, которая является одним из столпов ООП. Возможно, вы неправильно разделили код на классы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделайте открытые функции, которые будут возвращать значения полей этого класса.

Но что вы с ними хотите делать? Все функции вы уже реализовали в первом классе - просто используйте их во втором.

Comment: Спасибо, но вопрос в другом:  в классе Calculate у меня есть, допустим, переменная х. В другом классе я хочу обращаться к этой же переменной, как мне получить доступ?

Comment: @NewF, если я правильно понял, вы хотите внутри метода класса А работать с "потрохами" (полями) класса B? Если оставить в стороне рассуждения о том, зачем вам это надо, можно просто передавать в метод класса А ссылку или указатель на объект класса B. А дальше уже работать с B->x, B->y (B.x, B.y). Только вот они у вас объявлены как private, так что придётся либо перенести x и y в public, либо в класс B добавить методы для работы с ними (получения/изменения значения).